Finding specific coefficients of product of high-dimensional Fourier series faster than FFT
I need a fast algorithm to perform a specific Fourier-type computation in my physics research. Suppose I have the following two Fourier series in three dimensions
$$
a(t_1,t_2,t_3)=\sum_{j=-n}^{n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n} \sum_{l=-n}^{n} a_{j,k,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2} e^{ilt_3},         \qquad   b(t_1,0,t_3)=\sum_{j=-n}^{n} \sum_{l=-n}^{n} b_{j,0,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ilt_3}.
$$
The product of these Fourier series is another Fourier series, denoted by
$$
(ab)(t_1,t_2,t_3)=\sum_{j=-2n}^{2n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n} \sum_{l=-2n}^{2n} c_{j,k,l} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2} e^{ilt_3}.
$$
Suppose what we want to compute is not the entire 3D Fourier series of the product $ab$ with all its coefficients, but rather, only the subseries and coefficients corresponding to $l=0$, i.e., $c_{j,k,0}$ and
$$
\sum_{j=-2n}^{2n}\sum_{k=-n}^{n} c_{j,k,0} e^{ijt_1} e^{ikt_2}.
$$
It seems that using a 3D FFT, which has complexity $O(n^3\log(n))$ is a bit naive since I do not really want all the Fourier coefficients of the product $ab$, but rather the specific ones outlined above. Is there an algorithm faster than FFT and its $O(n^3\log(n))$ time complexity owing to the given structure of $a$ and $b$, along with my lack of need for all Fourier coefficients of the product? Can this be done in cubic time $O(n^3)$, or is that too optimistic? All help is greatly appreciated.
